# check if a checkbox is checked jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox, checked

Does anyone know why this isn't working.  It will always print 'unchecked'.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

function msg(x)
{

if($(x).attr('checked')){
  alert('checked!!');
}
else{
  alert('unchecked');
}

}

</script>


</head>
<body>

<form>
<input type="checkbox" id="fname2" onClick="msg(this.id)" /><br/>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are sending `this.id` to the function, then you are wrapping it in the `$()`.  This does not work.  You need just to send `this` to msg: `onClick="msg(this)"`.

Comment: If you want to send IDs to msg, you need to do: `$('#'+x)`.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
function chkChecked(elmt) {
    if($(elmt).is(':checked')) {
        alert('checked!!');
    }
    else alert('unchecked');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a [#](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) to tell jQuery that you want to select an id X rather than an element [X](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/).

```
if($('#'+x).attr('checked'))
```

Or, if you change `onClick="msg(this.id)"` to  `onClick="msg(this)"` you can use:

```
if($(x).attr('checked'))
```